# Powershell SHA-1 and base64 encode

Tags: powershell, sha1

Try to generate sha1 base64 hash of an empty string in powershell

```
$enc      = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$string   = ""
$data=$enc.GetBytes($string)
$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
$ResultHash = $sha1.ComputeHash($data)
$str_out = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ResultHash))
write-host $str_out
```

result is

```
MjE4IDU3IDE2MyAyMzggOTQgMTA3IDc1IDEzIDUwIDg1IDE5MSAyMzkgMTQ5IDk2IDI0IDE0NCAxNzUgMjE2IDcgOQ==
```

and I should have received

```
2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=
```

Please could someone advice?

Answer (score 0):

The output from `ComputeHash` *is already a byte array*, not a string - `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ResultHash)` makes no sense here.

Remove that part and it'll work as expected:

```
$enc      = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$string   = ""
$data=$enc.GetBytes($string)
$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
$ResultHash = $sha1.ComputeHash($data)
$str_out = [Convert]::ToBase64String($ResultHash)
write-host $str_out
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more concise version based on the [answer by Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66885593/179669).

With latest versions (PS 7 and Net Core) SHA1 has a static method HashData - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha1.hashdata#system-security-cryptography-sha1-hashdata(system-byte())) and [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/src/System/Security/Cryptography/SHA1.cs#L51)

```
$txt    = ""
$bytes  = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($txt)
$sha1   = [Security.Cryptography.SHA1]::HashData($bytes)
$result = [Convert]::ToBase64String($sha1)
Write-Host $result
```

Answer (score -1):

Your expected encoded base64 string is **not** UTF-8 encoded.

If you want to get `2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=` you have to replace :

`$str_out = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ResultHash))`

by

`$str_out = [Convert]::ToBase64String($ResultHash)`